# Pylint code rating fail under

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint, tox

I am building a `tox` file includes testing, coverage and running pylint. As you may know, pylint generates reports at the end of it includes code rating.

I want pylint not to break my tox build when the rating is over a score same as `--cov-fail-under` argument of `pytest-cov` package. By the way, there are two seperate pylint tasks which are for errors and general code rating. Of course I can't ignore pylint for errors. My need is for general code rating.

```
[testenv:pylint-code-quality]
basepython = python2.7
deps =
    pylint
    -retc/requirements/dev.txt
commands = pylint my_path -f colorized


[testenv:pylint-errors]
basepython = python2.7
deps =
    pylint
    -retc/requirements/dev.txt
commands = pylint my_path -f colorized --disable R,C,W
```

Is there a way to do it in pylint?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it exists but you may still submit a feature request on github (https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues)